# Separar um array em grupos?

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

Tenho o código abaixo respondido por uma dúvida similar a essa porém eu gostaria de fazer um upgrade, essa é a função atual:

```
function separar(base, maximo) {
  var resultado = [[]];
  var grupo = 0;

  for (var indice = 0; indice < base.length; indice++) {
    if (resultado[grupo] === undefined) {
      resultado[grupo] = [];
    }

    resultado[grupo].push(base[indice]);

    if ((indice + 1) % maximo === 0) {
      grupo = grupo + 1;
    }
  }

  return resultado;
}
```

Tal função irá separar um array comum em um multidimensional de grupos, de acordo com a quantidade de chaves por grupo que for especificado em `maximo`, porém agora preciso de uma função similar a mesma mas com a seguinte mudança:

> A última chave do grupo anterior deve ser a primeira do próximo grupo
>   a ser gerado.

Por exemplo:

```
var meuArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
/*separo meu array em grupos de 3 chaves*/
console.log(separar(meuArray, 3));
```

O exemplo acima deve imprimir:

```
   [
      0: [1, 2, 3]
      1: [4, 5, 6]
      2: [7, 8, 9]
      3: [10]
   ]
```

Com a alteração eu gostaria que imprimisse o array da seguinte maneira:

```
   [
      0: [1, 2, 3]
      1: [3, 4, 5]
      2: [5, 6, 7]
      3: [7, 8, 9]
      4: [9, 10, 1]
   ]
```

No último grupo já incluo  a primeira chave do próximo grupo, como eu posso fazer isso?

Comment: como ficaria se var meuArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];  e se var meuArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];

Comment: O penúltimo grupo no caso seria [9, 10, 11] e o ultimo ficaria [11, 1]

Comment: Caso tivesse 12 chaves o penúltimo ficaria [9, 10, 11] e o ultimo seria [11, 12, 1]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Da pra otimizar um pouco a função usando [Array#slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

**Resultado:**

```js
function separar(base, max) {
  var res = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < base.length; i = i+(max-1)) {
    res.push(base.slice(i,(i+max)));
  }
  res[res.length-1].push(base[0]);
  return res;
}

var meuArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
/*separo meu array em grupos de 3 chaves*/
console.log(separar(meuArray, 3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {top: 0; max-height: 100%!important}
```

A idéia é "cortar" o array pelas partes, mas se o grupo não for o primeiro cortar a partir do índice anterior com relação à posição atual e por fim adicionar o primeiro índice do array de origem ao último do array de resultado.

Comment: Por otimizar, você diz melhorar o desempenho e a velocidade com que minha função retorna um resultado em relação a minha atual?

Comment: Digo com relação a quantidade de código @LeoLetto

Comment: Com certeza a melhor resposta +1

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Melhor resposta com o melhor tempo +1

Comment: A título de curiosidade com relação a desempenho @LeoLetto: [jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/split-array-test)

Comment: Obrigado @LucasCosta

Answer (score 2):

Com poucas modificações, é possível chegar no resultado esperado:

```
function separar(base, maximo) {
  var resultado = [[]];
  var grupo = 0;
  var ultimo_valor = 0;

  for (var indice = 0; indice < base.length; indice++) {

    if (resultado[grupo] === undefined) {
      resultado[grupo] = [];
      // ultimo valor passa a ser o primero da nova linha
      resultado[grupo].push(ultimo_valor);
    }

    resultado[grupo].push(base[indice]);

    ultimo_valor = base[indice];

    if ((resultado[grupo].length) % maximo === 0) {
      grupo = grupo + 1;
    }

  }

  // adiciona ultimo elemento que vai apontar para o primeiro novamente
  if (typeof resultado[grupo] == 'undefined') {
      resultado[grupo] = [ultimo_valor, base[0]];
  } else if (resultado[grupo].length < maximo) {
      resultado[grupo].push(base[0]);
  } else {
      if (typeof resultado[grupo + 1] == 'undefined') {
         resultado[grupo + 1] = [ultimo_valor, base[0]];
      } else {
         resultado[grupo + 1].push(base[0]);  
      }
  }
  return resultado;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Podes ir verificando se cada grupo tem o tamanho certo e dentro desse `if` fazer a lógica toda para mudar de grupo e começar o novo já com o primeiro elemento.

Uma sugestão podia ser assim:

```js
function separar(base, maximo) {
  var resultado = [[]];
  var grupo = 0;

  for (var indice = 0; indice < base.length; indice++) {
    resultado[grupo].push(base[indice]);

    if (resultado[grupo].length === maximo) {
      grupo++;
      if (indice + 1 < base.length) resultado[grupo] = [base[indice]];
    }
  }

  return resultado;
}
var meuArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

console.log(separar(meuArray, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function separar(arr, len){
    var r = [], i = 0, last;
    r[i] = []; 
    do{
        do{
            r[i].push(last = arr.shift() || r[0][0]);
        }while(r[i].length < len);
        if(arr.length >0){
            r[i++] = [];
            r[i].push(last);
        }
    }while(arr.length != 0);

    return r;
}


var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
console.log(separar(arr, 3));

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];
console.log(separar(arr, 3));
```